# Facebook app login issues from public user

Tags: facebook, magento, authentication, public

I created Facebook app and integrated with magento, when public user try to login to the fb it shows this error.

[image: Facebook app login issue from public users<code>enter here</code>]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2Zsn.png)

My requirement is when user login Facebook from magento site need to display user images and albums, but this process working with admin details (Getting the profile images and albums from admin details )

```js
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({ appId: facebook_app_id, 
        status: true, 
        cookie: true,
        xfbml: true,
        oauth: true});
  function updateButton(response) {
    var button = document.getElementById('fb-auth');
        
    if (response.authResponse) {
      //user is already logged in and connected
     document.getElementById("fbaccesstoken").value = response.authResponse.accessToken;
      var userInfo = document.getElementById('user-info'),
          photos_album  = document.getElementById('photos_album');
      FB.api('/me', function(response) {
       /* userInfo.innerHTML = '<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/' 
           + response.id + '/picture" />' + response.name;
        button.innerHTML = 'Logout';*/
      });
      FB.api('/me/albums', function(response){
        var l=response.data.length,
            rs_all,
            all_img;
        if(l > 0){
            rs_all ='<select id="fb_album" onchange="get_all_photos(this.value)"><option value="0">-- Select your album --</option>';
            for (var i=0; i<l; i++){
                var album = response.data[i],
                    albumid = album.id;
                    rs_all += '<option value="'+album.id+'">'+album.name+'</option>';
            }
            rs_all += '</select>';
            userInfo.innerHTML = rs_all;
        }
        //
      });
      get_all_photos = function(id){
        if(id==0){
            photos_album.innerHTML = '';
            return;
        }
        FB.api("/"+id+"/photos",function(response){
         console.log(response);
            var photos = response["data"],
                pt_result = '<ul>';
            for(var pt=0;pt<photos.length;pt++) {
                console.log(photos[pt].images);
                //pt_result += '<li><img color="" src="'+photos[pt].images[0].source+'" /></li>';
                //pt_result += '<li><img color="" src="https://graph.facebook.com/' + photos[pt].id + '/picture'+'" /></li>';
                pt_result +=  '<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/'+photos[pt].id + '/picture?access_token='+document.getElementById("fbaccesstoken").value+'" style="margin-right:5px"/>';
            }
            photos_album.innerHTML = pt_result+'</ul>';
        });
      }
      button.onclick = function() {
        FB.logout(function(response) {
          var userInfo = document.getElementById('user-info');
          userInfo.innerHTML="";
    });
      };
    } else {
      //user is not connected to your app or logged out
      //button.innerHTML = 'Please Login Facebook';
      button.onclick = function() {
        FB.login(function(response) {
      if (response.authResponse) {
            FB.api('/me', function(response) {
          var userInfo = document.getElementById('user-info');
          //userInfo.innerHTML = 
           //     '<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/' 
            //+ response.id + '/picture" style="margin-right:5px"/>' 
           // + response.name;
        });    
          } else {
            //user cancelled login or did not grant authorization
          }
        }, {scope:'user_photos'});    
      }
    }
  }

  // run once with current status and whenever the status changes
  FB.getLoginStatus(updateButton);
  FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', updateButton);    
};
```

Comment: any one please give the conclusion on this issue

Comment: what exactly does not work?

Comment: Public user n't able to login,

Comment: Error is "App Not Setup: This app is still in development mode, and you don't have access to it. Switch to a registered test user or ask an app admin for permissions."   but i can login with admin details and getting admin images albums

Comment: read my answer, that error is very clear

Answer (score 1):

```js
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({ appId: facebook_app_id, 
        status: true, 
        cookie: true,
        xfbml: true,
        oauth: true});
  function updateButton(response) {
    var button = document.getElementById('fb-auth');
        
    if (response.authResponse) {
      //user is already logged in and connected
     document.getElementById("fbaccesstoken").value = response.authResponse.accessToken;
      var userInfo = document.getElementById('user-info'),
          photos_album  = document.getElementById('photos_album');
      FB.api('/me', function(response) {
       /* userInfo.innerHTML = '<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/' 
           + response.id + '/picture" />' + response.name;
        button.innerHTML = 'Logout';*/
      });
      FB.api('/me/albums', function(response){
        var l=response.data.length,
            rs_all,
            all_img;
        if(l > 0){
            rs_all ='<select id="fb_album" onchange="get_all_photos(this.value)"><option value="0">-- Select your album --</option>';
            for (var i=0; i<l; i++){
                var album = response.data[i],
                    albumid = album.id;
                    rs_all += '<option value="'+album.id+'">'+album.name+'</option>';
            }
            rs_all += '</select>';
            userInfo.innerHTML = rs_all;
        }
        //
      });
      get_all_photos = function(id){
        if(id==0){
            photos_album.innerHTML = '';
            return;
        }
        FB.api("/"+id+"/photos",function(response){
         console.log(response);
            var photos = response["data"],
                pt_result = '<ul>';
            for(var pt=0;pt<photos.length;pt++) {
                console.log(photos[pt].images);
                //pt_result += '<li><img color="" src="'+photos[pt].images[0].source+'" /></li>';
                //pt_result += '<li><img color="" src="https://graph.facebook.com/' + photos[pt].id + '/picture'+'" /></li>';
                pt_result +=  '<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/'+photos[pt].id + '/picture?access_token='+document.getElementById("fbaccesstoken").value+'" style="margin-right:5px"/>';
            }
            photos_album.innerHTML = pt_result+'</ul>';
        });
      }
      button.onclick = function() {
        FB.logout(function(response) {
          var userInfo = document.getElementById('user-info');
          userInfo.innerHTML="";
    });
      };
    } else {
      //user is not connected to your app or logged out
      //button.innerHTML = 'Please Login Facebook';
      button.onclick = function() {
        FB.login(function(response) {
      if (response.authResponse) {
            FB.api('/me', function(response) {
          var userInfo = document.getElementById('user-info');
          //userInfo.innerHTML = 
           //     '<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/' 
            //+ response.id + '/picture" style="margin-right:5px"/>' 
           // + response.name;
        });    
          } else {
            //user cancelled login or did not grant authorization
          }
        }, {scope:'user_photos'});    
      }
    }
  }

  // run once with current status and whenever the status changes
  FB.getLoginStatus(updateButton);
  FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', updateButton);    
};
```

Comment: You really should add some explanation to your code. It is considered good practice and helps others to understand.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as the error message tells you, your App is in development mode. Got to the "Status & Review" tab of your App and use the switch next to this text:

> Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?

That being said, you need to go through a review process with user_photos or that permission will only work for users with a role in your App. Everything you need to know about Login Review can be found here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review

Btw, you don´t need `getLoginStatus` AND subscribing to the event `auth.statusChange`. Here is a tutorial with detailed explanation about everything you need for login and refreshing the Access Token for returning users: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/